# tar pre-run to evaluate expected size or amount of files

Tags: tar, evaluate

The problem:
I have a back-end process that at some point he collect and build a big tar file. 
This tar receive few directories and an exclude files. 
the process can take up to few minutes and i want to report in my front-end process (GUI) about the progress of the taring process (This is a big issue for a user that press download button and it seems like nothing is happening...).

i know i can use -v -R in the tar command and count files and size progress but i am looking for some kind of tar pre-run mode / dry run to help me evaluate either the expected number of files or the expected tar size.

the command I am using: `tar -jcf 'FILE.tgz' 'exclude_files' 'include_dirs_and_files'`

10x for everyone who is willing to assist.

Answer (score 16):

You can pipe the output to the `wc` tool instead of actually making a file.

With file listing (verbose):

```
[git@server]$ tar czvf - ./test-dir | wc -c
./test-dir/
./test-dir/test.pdf
./test-dir/test2.pdf
2734080
```

Without:

```
[git@server]$ tar czf - ./test-dir | wc -c
2734080
```

Comment: Good catch.  For info to future readers, the `-` tells tar to output to stdout (where it'll be piped to wc).

Comment: To confirm: Is this solution a "tar pre-run mode / dry run to help me evaluate either the expected number of files or the expected tar size" (without actually zipping/creating the tar)?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you run a

```
DIRS=("./test-dir" "./other-dir-to-test")
find ${DIRS[@]} -type f | wc -l
```

beforehand. This gets all the files (`-type f`) one per line and counts the number of files. DIRS is an array in bash, so you can store the folders in a variable

If you want to know the size of all the stored files, you can use `du`

```
DIRS=("./test-dir" "./other-dir-to-test")
du -c -d 0 ${DIRS[@]} | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'
```

This prints the disk usage with `du`, calculates a grand total (`-c` flag), gets the last line (example `4378921 total`), and uses just the first column with `awk`

Comment: I note that tar and find don't always agree on the number of files; e.g., on my Mac, tar seems to skip files indexed for Finder preview wheres find does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific trick of tar.
If you output to `/dev/null`, it doesn't read the file content, so:

```
root@grigio:/bidone# time tar cpf /dev/null --totals Amerighuccio/
Total bytes written: 26924871680 (26GiB, 11GiB/s)

real    0m2,320s
user    0m0,914s
sys     0m1,401s
```